# Type has no member - App Development Project 2, Apple Pie

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, member, xcode9

I'm working through App Development with Swift, and I'm stuck on the last bit of the second project, Apple Pie.

In the guide, it has you create a new file, Game.Swift, and a struct Game inside that file. Later on, it tells you to

> Create a computed property called formattedWord within the definition of Game. Here's one way to compute formattedWord:

```
var formattedWord: String {
    var guessedWord = ""
    for letter in word.characters {
        if guessedLetters.contains(letter) {
            guessedWord += "\(letter)"
        } else {
            guessedWord += "_"
        } 
    }
    return guessedWord
}
```

> Now that formattedWord is a property that your UI can display, try using it for the text of currentWordLabel inside of updateUI().

```
func updateUI() {
    correctWordLabel.text = game.formattedWord
    scoreLabel.text = "Wins: \(totalWins), Losses: \(totalLosses)"
    treeImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Tree \(currentGame.incorrectMovesRemaining)")
}
```

I've done this EXACTLY, I've checked the code and the guide about 700 times, not to mention google searches and looking at a similar (but vaguely answered) question here on SO, but I still can't get it fixed. I found a solution that said to change

```
correctWordLabel.text = game.formattedWord
```

to

```
correctWordLabel.text = currentGame.formattedWord
```

but that's not working, either. If anyone can help, I would surely appreciate it. I've attached scrseenshots, just for further clarification.

[View Controller screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Xj6r.png)

[struct Game screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H28fk.png)

I feel like I somehow haven't declared formattedWord correctly inside the struct Game, but I've done everything the guide says exactly. I'm still getting

> Type 'Game' has no member 'formattedWord'

on line 45 of the View Controller. Please help!

Comment: Please don't post screen shots of your code, post the actual code so that people who want to try it out can copy-paste instead of typing it in again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select all the code, and auto indent it (keyboard short cuts: ctrl+a, then ctrl+i). You would see the problem pretty quickly as the resulting code would look like

```
struct Game {
    var word: String
    var incorrectMovesRemaining: Int
    var guessedLetters: [Character]
    mutating func playerGuessed(letter: Character) {
        guessedLetters.append(letter)
        if !word.characters.contains(letter) {
            incorrectMovesRemaining -= 1

            var formattedWord: String {
                var guessedWord = ""
                for letter in word.characters {
                    if guessedLetters.contains(letter) {
                        guessedWord += "\(letter)"
                    } else {
                        guessedWord += "_"
                    }
                }
                return guessedWord
            }
        } // <-- This is where your problem is
    }
}
```

In the code you currently have, you're declaring the `formattedWord` variable inside the `playersGuessed` function, so nothing outside of that function can access that variable.

Your code isn't properly formatted in your `Game` struct. Notice the 3 `}` on lines 31->33. That is a big red flag. The problem is that you didn't close the `if` statement on line 17, and the function on line 15. You need to add the closing `}` to line 19/20. Your `Game` struct should look like this.

```
struct Game {
    var word: String
    var incorrectMovesRemaining: Int
    var guessedLetters: [Character]
    mutating func playerGuessed(letter: Character) {
        guessedLetters.append(letter)
        if !word.characters.contains(letter) {
            incorrectMovesRemaining -= 1
        } // <-- This is where your problem is
    }

    var formattedWord: String {
        var guessedWord = ""
        for letter in word.characters {
            if guessedLetters.contains(letter) {
                guessedWord += "\(letter)"
            } else {
                guessedWord += "_"
            }
        }
        return guessedWord
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much. I've been staring at this for something like 3 hours and it's 3am, so I guess I just became blind to it. Thank you, again. It's always the little things that seem to jam me up like this!

Comment: Now I'm getting a new error, use of unresolved identifier 'word' on the Game.struct

Comment: TOTALLY FIXED; Thanks so much.

Comment: Good to hear you got it fixed. Was about to say it runs fine in a playground, so I wouldn't be able to help more without seeing the new code. But, if you solved it, great!